# JSON from streeteasy api php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

So maybe I am doing this wrong but I am trying to get information using the streeteasy api but when I use this code (below) it doesn't return anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://streeteasy.com/nyc/api/areas/search?q=soho&key=API_KEY&format=json');
$data = json_decode($url, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Check your error log. If you are having problems, it will most likely be throwing an error that will end up in your log.

Comment: would I have to use the json_last_error() function?

Comment: That is not the error log. I mean the apache error logs. The log that apache/php writes to when ever there is an error. The problem most likely has nothing to do with the json but with fetching the page. Have you checked that the file_get_contents works?

Comment: Just throwing it out there. Did you replace `API_KEY` with your actual API key? If not then the API will returned `Not Authorized`. Try `echo $url;` to see what that gives you.

Comment: The api within the $url string is the one that belongs to me. I tried to echo $url and got nothing. I checked my log and I got "could not lookup DNS configuration info service: (ipc/send) invalid destination port." Could it be that I am using a local server?

Comment: I think that stackoverflow filtered out the api key and replaced it with API_KEY. But I am using my own.

Comment: _“I think […]”_ – it does say “edited 1 hour ago [by] Rocket Hazmat” under your posting now for a reason …

Comment: do add error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1); before the $url declaration- It should output on the screen quite a few things. Also it could be that allow_url_fopen is turned off on your machine, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen